# Two step Generalized Method of Moments (Newey 1994). $\hat{W}$ matrix depending on the nuisance parameter

Tags: econometrics, theory, gmm

Suppose that I am working in a model containing a nuisance parameter $h$ and a finite dimensional parameter of interest $\theta$, whose true values are $h_0$ and $\theta_0$, respectively.
Newey (1994) proves the asymptotic properties of a two-step GMM with a non parametric first step, and studies the properties of
$\hat{\theta}= \arg \max_{\theta} m_{n}(\theta, \hat{h})^{T} \hat{W} m_{n}(\theta,\hat{h}) $
where
$m_{n}(\theta,h)=\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n m(W_i,\theta,h)$
and $\mathbb{E}[m(W,\theta_0,h_0)]=0$.

In this setup, can one choose $\hat{W}$ (positive semi-definite) to depend on $\hat{h}$ and still expect the asymptotic results to hold, if all the regularity conditions are met and $\hat{W} \to W$ in probability ?
There are no indications in the papers that $\hat{W}$ cannot depend on the nuisance parameter.

Answer (score 2):

As long as $\hat{W}\rightarrow W$ where $W$ is the inverse of the variance-covariance matrix of moments, then all of the asymptotic properties hold. You seem to be asking if this applies in your case.

I think you would need to justify that $\hat{h}\rightarrow h$ and that $\hat{W}(h)$ is "continuous" in $h$. Given this, $\hat{W}(\hat{h})\rightarrow W$ and all is well.

Comment: Does it have to be the inverse variance-covariance matrix of moments? Or W hat could be a positive definite matrix, that converges to a positive definite matrix W. Not looking for efficiejxy.

Comment: If you aren't looking for efficiency, then you are correct, you just need convergence to a positive definite matrix.

Comment: I am afraid that nuisance parameters are not satisfying the requirement $\hat{h}\rightarrow h_0$ when sample size goes to infinity.